# Need a update-query to populate table column "display_order"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table on mysql with these columns:

- id
- property_id
- display_order

The data is to be like this:

```
1 , 1 , 1
2 , 1 , 2
3 , 1 , ...
3 , 2 , 1
4 , 2 , 2
5 , 2 , ...
```

but the `display_order` is currently set to 1 on all rows.

I need a mysql query in order to set `display_order` as given in the above example.

This a 1 to N realation ship

- property table
- photo table

... = 3 , 4  5 ... N ( <-dysplay order)

I don't no how perform this update.

[image]

Comment: Please describe in detail the behavior of the required update query. What have you done already? Why is it not working?

Comment: Also what is ... ? A synonym for '3' ?

Comment: i update the question with more info and a image!

Comment: You mean: the order := 1 + the number of people with a lower id for the same attribute. Have you considered counting them ?

Answer (score 0):

create an UPDATE with a @variable, give it an initial value ..., with case change ... to 1, 1 to 2 and 2 to ... and assign its value to the colunm, updating fields from a subselect ordered by the columns that form your key.